# What is the Link that I should insert for Live OWL Documentation Environment (LODE)?

Tags: ontology, semantic-web, protege

I want to publish my ontology online. I saw many ontologies are using https://essepuntato.it/lode/
and I do not understand what is this link that is needed? Can I just use the link that is in Protege's  default Ontology IRI?
E.g.: http://www.semanticweb.org/PCuser/ontologies/2023/1/untitled-ontology-66

If not, how can I proceed?

I constantly get different errors and not sure what to do.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

LODE can generate a HTML document about an OWL ontology.

If you want to use their hosted service (instead of running it [locally](https://github.com/essepuntato/LODE)), you have to enter the URL of your published (publicly available) RDF file which represents that ontology.

Before publishing your ontology somewhere, make sure ***not*** to use the URI prefix Protégé adds by default (in your case `http://www.semanticweb.org/PCuser/ontologies/2023/1/untitled-ontology-66#`) for the URIs of your own terms and individuals. This semanticweb.org URI is just a placeholder. You have to use URIs which you control (e.g., because it’s your own domain name, or because the owner gave you permission etc.).